# Required Resolution Graphics for Storyboard Design iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiimageview, uistoryboard

After trying hard to create screen which support multiple resolutions, I can't able to get success in deciding what resolution graphics I require to use for @1x, @2x and @3x sizes.
Because in Storyboard also device is not displaying in exact screen size resolution, may be half width and height is running. 
So please clarify about this too.

Please check this reference image:
[image]

At present I have considered iPhoneSE as base view because my graphics @1x exist in this resolution. But when I load image into UIImageView its looking too bigger compare to requirements.

So what changes I require to do for this correction?
Also provide me some suggestion about resources, I require to use for handling multiple iPhone sizes.

**EDIT:**

When I try to resize UIImageView - it get cut from all sides:

[image]

Comment: in above SS , its seems that your image is larger than imageview,resize the image according the imageview size

Comment: I am asking storyboard iPhoneSE not following same resolution because I design it in exact same resolution. But after placing I realise storyboard following may be half resolution.

Comment: In this case you have to apply constraints on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can get more clarity after read it:**
There is something to understand. By creating 2x and 3x images, you can't expect exact same layout from each iPhone screen. The layout will be different from screen to screen. 1x, 2x and 3x image sizes dealing with only the pixel density of the screen.

Suppose you have an image which is 320 * 70 and you are creating

[image]

if the image size is 100 * 100

```
@1x -> 100 * 100

@2x -> 200 * 200

@3x -> 300 * 300
```

[image]

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/image-size-and-resolution/

**You can also do like this:**

The best way to achieve this is by using an "Asset Manager" as the other answers have pointed to, and by using a "Vector" image. A PDF image is Vector, and both "Adobe Photoshop" and "Adobe Illustrator" allow you to "Save as..." PDF. So:

[image]

Comment: so whether I require to load half size graphics for application? At present its looking like double size.

Comment: Yah, you have to reduce the width and set the image give proper layout to it. Provide all 1x, 2x, and 3x images in assets.

Comment: I am up voting your answer because many concepts get cleared after this :)

Comment: Thank you very much @Siddharth

Comment: Yes I have already applied 1x, 2x and 3x image assets - when I resize image view it get cut off, please check edited question...

Comment: No thank you - still you have to help me to reach at target :)

Comment: Bro you should set property for UIImageView either from storyboard inspector or programmatically like imageView.contentMode

Comment: One more question - so always I require to put half size image in storyboard canvas? rather than actual resolution of device...

Comment: This may helps you: http://roadfiresoftware.com/2015/04/how-to-scale-an-image-view-based-on-device-size-with-auto-layout-in-interface-builder/ @Siddharth

Answer (score 1):

Select your regular device and Apply proper constraint on it or use autoresizing option like this

[image]

Comment: Please check my edited question, after resize of UIImageView.

Comment: I have upvoted your answer too because Content Mode change worked for me :)